# Problema con la hora al editar un registro aplicacion web java utilizando ejb + jsf?

Tags: java, sql, jsf, web, ejb

Estoy utilizando Glassfish server 4.1.1, java EE7 web, jdk 1.8 y jsf 2.2

Al editar o guardar un registro la hora o bueno la fecha tambien difieren entre lo que se guarda en la bdd(lo cual esta correcto) y lo que muestra el datatable(lo cual esta incorrecto). En la siguiente imagen se muestra el data table (hora incorrecta):[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahora lo que se muestra en el campo de la bdd(fecha correcta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Metodos get y set de la clase y referencia al campo de la tabla en la clase  usuario. java**

public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

```
public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
    this.updated = updated;
}
```

public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

```
public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```

@Column(name = "CREATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

@Column(name = "UPDATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updated;

**form.xml**

```html
<h:outputLabel value="Modificado:" for="updated"/>
        <h:inputText id="updated" value="#{usuarioController.selected.updated}" title="Actualizado" disabled="true">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
        </h:inputText>
```

```html
<h:outputLabel value="Creado    :" for="created"/>
        <h:inputText id="created" value="#{usuarioController.selected.created}" title="Creado" disabled="true">
          <br></br>
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
        </h:inputText>
```

**Metodos en el controlador para crear y editar un usuario**

```html
public String agregar(){
        
        Date d= new Date();
        selected.setCreated(d);
        selected.setUpdated(d);
        dao.create(selected);        
        return "/usuario/index";
        
    }

public String edit(int codigo){
    selected = dao.find(codigo);
    return "/usuario/edit";    
}

public String guardar(){
    Date d = new Date();        
    selected.setUpdated(d);
    dao.edit(selected);
    return "index";
}
```

PD. estoy utilizando la propia base de datos de netbeans que viene incluida en los servicios

Comment: El problema no es ni de JSF ni de proyectos web ni de EJB, es decir, ninguna de esas etiquetas debería pertenecer a la pregunta. El problema debe ser la zona horaria que se usa en la base de datos y en tu aplicación. Puedes ver esto si colocas que imprima la zona horaria de tu fecha, donde verás la diferencia de horas p.e. uno dirá UTC y el otro UTC -5 (o +5).

Answer (score 0):

El problema claramente es la zona horaria. Los objetos de tipo `Date` no tienen conocimiento de la zona horaria, por lo tanto, JSF como tu adaptador de persistencia JPA están realizando conversiones de forma incorrecta. Para convertir de forma exitósa las fechas, todos los componentes involucrados en el sistema deben comunicarse usando la misma zona horaria en la configuración.

El primer componente es el sistema operativo, el cuál mantiene la **hora local** usando una **zona horaria local**.

El segundo componente es la **JVM**, la cuál en caso de no haber definifo la propiedad de sistema `user.timezone`, usará la **zona horaria local** como el valor de retorno para `TimeZone.getDefault()` inicialmente, que representa la zona **horaria por defecto** en varios de los siguientes componentes.

El tercer componente es el servidor de aplicaciones y las aplicaciones web desplegadas.

Las aplicaciones web (y sus dependencias empaquetedas) generalmente tienen el acceso libre a invocar `TimeZone.setDefault()`, una invocación a  este método podría parecer nada dañina, sin embargo es **dañina completamente**; Imagina que la *Aplicación Web A* trabaja con la zona horaria `Etc/UTC` por ser la zona horaria local y realiza todas las conversiones acorde a esta suposición, posteriormente una *Aplicación Web B* cambia la zona horaria invocando `TimeZone.setDefault()`, el resultado es más que obvio.

El objeto `Date` no guarda internamente información sobre la zona horaria, representa un instante de tiempo único no afectado por zona horaria ni horario de verano, es decir, para mostrar la fecha correcta es necesario convertir este valor universal a la zona horaria deseada. Todo esto por lo general es realizado por los siguientes componentes.

Cuando de usa **JPA**, uno de los componentes de la Aplicación Web es la **adaptador de persistencia**, el cuál decide como convertir un objeto de tipo `Date` a la debida representación para una sentencia SQL (sea o no sea una sentencia preparada), esta conversión por lo general usa `TimeZone.getDefault()` para realizar esta conversión. Si las aplicaciones desplegadas no tienen la mala práctica de invocar `TimeZone.setDefault()`, este componente no presentará nungún problema de conversión.

El ***framework* de presentación o vista** es un componente indispensable de la Aplicación Web, este al igual que el adaptador de persistencia, realiza conversiones. En el caso de **JSF**, las conversiones de fechas se definen a a través de la etiqueta `<f:convertDateTime/>`, tal cuál en el ejemplo del problema. Uno de los atributos de esta etiqueta es `timeZone` para definir la **zona horaria deseada** para la conversión. De acuerdo a la documentación, este atributo no tiene un valor por defecto, por lo tanto, la fecha mostrada para el mismo instante de tiempo será diferente, según la implementación de JSF usada.

La solución más rápida a este problema en específio es aparentemente definir el atributo `timeZone`  en `<f:convertDateTime/>`, algo similar al siguiente código:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Creado    :" for="created"/>
<h:inputText id="created" value="#{usuarioController.selected.created}" title="Creado" disabled="true">
    <br></br>
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" timeZone="America/Mexico_City"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Una solución alternativa sería usar un adaptador de persistencia con soporte para la clase `LocalDateTime`, la cúal representa una fecha y hora locales (sin zona horaria). Dependiendo de la implementación de JSF y servidor de aplicación, podría ser necesario escribir y registrar un convertidor.

Enlaces con más información:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html